# Access TextBlock text in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am new to C#/XAML coding and I have the following question.

I have this ListView and I have added Aditional Templates to the generated Items

```
 <ListView x:Name="lvItems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="251" Margin="10,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="1346" SelectionChanged="lvItems_SelectionChanged" Foreground="{x:Null}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard500x130ItemTemplate}">
```

If I go to edit the template I get the following code

```
<!-- Grid-appropriate 500 by 130 pixel item template as seen in the GroupDetailPage -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="Standard500x130ItemTemplate">
  <Grid Height="110"
        Width="480"
        Margin="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            Width="110"
            Height="110">
      <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
             Stretch="UniformToFill"
             AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />
    </Border>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="10,0,0,0">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                 Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"
                 TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}"
                 Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}"
                 TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                 Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"
                 MaxHeight="60" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I want to access the Texblocks Title, Subtitle, Description to add data that I have parsed from an XML File. I guess to to that I need to access the Binding  of each TextBlock but I have no clue how to do that. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView`, and then the fields will populate for each item, based on the template you created.

```
lvItems.ItemsSource = MyObjectsCollection;
```

Here I'm assuming `MyObjectCollection` is a collection of your objects.  Judging from your template, the data class should look something like this:

```
public class TheObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

So `MyObjectsCollection` should be an array (or IEnumerable, or List) of `TheObject` objects.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I couldn't find. I was searching for hours!! Can you suggest a place where I can start learning these things? I tried msdn but I don't know where to start.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Christos312 no prob, glad I could help.  In terms of resources, if you're not able to find any good tutorials, etc, then I think the articles on MSDN are always pretty good.  Start here for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx

Comment: the article that you gave me it was the one I was reading. I couldn't make it work reading that one thats why I decided to post here. Anyway I will study the article more carefully then.
Cheers!